# JWT implementation and protection against CSRF and XSS

Tags: authentication, xss, csrf, jwt, owasp

I have been going through OWASP guidelines on managing JWT based authentication. So, I have decided to change my current JWT implementation as per that.

Flow is as below.

*When authenticated successfully,*

1. Generate `accessToken` as JWT also an opaque `refreshToken` *(Also add a bcrypt `hash` of some random string as `csrf` in the payload) *
2. Store in the cookie with `httpOnly` and secure flags and `cookieName` as auth

   `cookie.auth = JSON.stringify({ accessToken, refreshToken})`
3. Store `refreshToken` as `bcrypt` hash with expiry in database
4. Also, add custom header X-CSRF with csrf string without hash

*When request arrives on `server`,*

1. Parse cookie and check for `accessToken` ,`refreshToken` nad `csrf`
2. Check `accessToken` validity and integrity
3. Compare `csrf` hash in header with the one inside `accessToken`
4. Process the request if valid or throw 401

*When request comes to refresh the token,*

1. Parse cookie and check for `accessToken` ,`refreshToken` and `csrf`
2. Compare `csrf` hash in header with the one inside accessToken
3. Decode `accessToken` get the user details

   ```
   const user = jwt.decode(accessToken)
   ```
4. Check if user exist in database and is not blocked, also check for refresh token and expiry
5. Fetch refresh token from database and compare it with the one passed in the cookie
6. If valid generate a new `accessToken` with options as above also a `csrf` token. If not throw 401

There one problem with the above approach, handling authentication  is job of `auth` srever.

This server also generates the `accessToken` and `refreshToken` and then it stores them in the cookie on the client side.

How other server can get this cookie?

So, X created the cookie with httpOnly and secure flag. Now this cookie must be sent to Y.
In this case it violates the security implemented itself, what are workaround here?

Am I missing anything here, can this process be optimized or simplified?

Also, client can be both a browser or an android or iOS app.
Please help, thanks!

Comment: Please do not post images of text as a post. Copy/paste the text. Plus the image is very difficult to read.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @schroeder I understand. But if you click on the image, it is fairly readable thanks.

Comment: @Sjoerd Is the current approach fine or do I need to change something considering both type of clients android app and web app. Also, check implementation of the refresh token.

Comment: Please replace the image.

Comment: _*"But if you click on the image, it is fairly readable thanks."*_, maybe for you. This rule is to make our site accessible for the visually-impaired, people who do not speak English and need to translate the page, or anybody else who uses screen-reading software. These tools do not work well on text inside images. Not to mention search engines so that others with the same question can easily find your post.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth That's a fair point, I completely agree. I will convert it into text. Thanks